# getting the value of static method in javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, static

i can't figure it out on how to get the values of a static method of a class. my code is below.

```
class Field {
    constructor(rows = 11, cols = 10) {
    this.numRows = rows
    this.numCols = cols
    }

    static loadFromFileContents(contents) {
        this.numCols = contents.split('x')[0]
        this.numRows = contents.split('x')[1]

    }
}
const contents = `4 x 5`
const field = Field.loadFromFileContents(contents)
console.log(field.numCols)
console.log(field.numRows)
```

first of all, i want to get the instance of the static method. something like this `instanceof(field)`, it should be equal to 'Field'. but i don't know if my syntax is correct for getting the instance. Second i want the return value of `field.numCols` should be equal to 4 because of the first split value and 
`field.numRows` should be equal to 5. sorry i'm not that familiar with static method of a class. i hope you can help me with my problem. thank you so much.

Comment: yes, mybad i did not notice it. i already fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the static method needs to parse the passed string and return a new `Field` instance:

```js
class Field {
  constructor(rows = 11, cols = 10) {
    this.numRows = rows
    this.numCols = cols
  }

  static loadFromFileContents(contents) {
    const [rows, cols] = contents.split(' x ');
    return new Field(rows, cols);
  }
}
const contents = `4 x 5`
const field = Field.loadFromFileContents(contents)
console.log(field.numCols)
console.log(field.numRows)
```

Comment: wow thanks. it worked. how about this assert.instanceOf(field, Field)? how can i make the instance of the field equal to Field?

Comment: You can use `field instanceof Field`, which shows that it resolves to `true`